# Sequelize query: how to apply where clause to an aliased column

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a column in my `Property` table which is an aliased `sequelize.literal` returning a boolean. But I cannot figure out how to query on this aliased column. Using this code below results to an error:

```
Property.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [
      ...,
      [sequelize.literal("date_acquired + (interval '1 year' *  estimated_useful_life) < CURRENT_DATE"), 'beyond_useful_life']
    ],
    where: {beyond_useful_life: true},
  })
```

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: you could try sequelize col operator on you where condition `where: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('beyond_useful_life'), true),` [Find More usage here](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/sequelize/sequelize/manual/querying.html)

Comment: @SanuKhan this did not work for me unfortunately. this resulted to the node program crashing.

Comment: may i know what exactly the error is

Comment: Just use the same literal in `sequelize.where`